# compare multiple rows python

Tags: python, compare, rows

I'm new to programming.
Please help me with the following task.
I have a csv data with unknown rows. But each row has the same number of elements as following:

```
Right   \FR\Window open\Start   16.9    11.2    18.2
Right   \FR\Window open\Start   16.5    11.7    17.5
Right   \FR\Window open\Start   16.9    11.7    18
Right   \FR\Window open\End     7.61    1.76    8.37
Right   \FR\Window open\End     7.3     1.74    8.6
Right   \FR\Window open\End     7.64    2.45    8.43
Right   \FR\Window close\Start  13      8.2     14.4
Right   \FR\Window close\Start  12.9    7.55    14.5
```

I would like to compute the average for those lines with the same string `\FR\Window open\Start` and `\FR\Window open\End` and so on.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the csv module in python to get the data from a csv file like so:

```
import csv

start_values = {'col3':[], 'col4':[], 'col5':[]}
end_values = {'col3':[], 'col4':[], 'col5':[]}

with open('example.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        if row['col2'] == '\FR\Window open\Start':
            start_values['col3'].append(float(row['col3']))
            start_values['col4'].append(float(row['col4']))
            start_values['col5'].append(float(row['col5']))
        if row['col2'] == '\FR\Window open\End':
            end_values['col3'].append(float(row['col3']))
            end_values['col4'].append(float(row['col4']))
            end_values['col5'].append(float(row['col5']))

    csvfile.close()
print('Start average for col3: {:.2f}, col4: {:.2f}, col5: {:.2f}'.format(sum(start_values['col3'])/len(start_values['col3']), sum(start_values['col4'])/len(start_values['col4']), sum(start_values['col5'])/len(start_values['col5'])))
print('End average for col3: {:.2f}, col4: {:.2f}, col5: {:.2f}'.format(sum(end_values['col3'])/len(end_values['col3']), sum(end_values['col4'])/len(end_values['col4']), sum(end_values['col5'])/len(end_values['col5'])))
```

Using this comma-separated example.csv with your data,

```
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5
Right,\FR\Window open\Start,16.9,11.2,18.2
Right,\FR\Window open\Start,16.5,11.7,17.5
Right,\FR\Window open\Start,16.9,11.7,18
Right,\FR\Window open\End,7.61,1.76,8.37
Right,\FR\Window open\End,7.3,1.74,8.6
Right,\FR\Window open\End,7.64,2.45,8.43
Right,\FR\Window close\Start,13,8.2,14.4
Right,\FR\Window close\Start,12.9,7.55,14.5
```

this program reads each row into a Dictionary for easy access as you can see in the ifs looking for the Start and End (`if row['col2'] == '\FR\Window open\Start':`). Then it fills the `start_values` and the `end_values` Dictionaries with their respective values. In the end those dictionaries will look like this:

```
{'col3': [16.9, 16.5, 16.9, 13.0, 12.9], 'col4': [11.2, 11.7, 11.7, 8.2, 7.55], 'col5': [18.2, 17.5, 18.0, 14.4, 14.5]}
```

The one above is `start_values`. Each column of numbers on the "Start" rows is neatly packed into a list. Then all you have to do is `print(sum(list)/len(list))` and there's your average, neatly formatted into 2 decimal places using String.format.

You can learn more about working with CSV files on the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html). And [here](https://mkaz.blog/code/python-string-format-cookbook/) is a handy guide for formatting strings!

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I understand your solution. unfortunately I still have an issue when I run this code: print('Start average for col3: {:.2f}, col4: {:.2f}, col5: {:.2f}'.format(sum(start_values['col3'])/len(start_values['col3']), sum(start_values['col4'])/len(start_values['col4']), sum(start_values['col5'])/len(start_values['col5']))) ZeroDivisionError: division by zero I'll try to look closer tomorrow.

Comment: @AlexeAdrianMarius is your csv file comma separated? That error means the length of one of the lists is zero, so my guess would be there's a problem getting the data out of the csv. This code only works if the csv file is formatted like the one in my answer; you can check by opening it with notepad.

Comment: Many thanks. It is working now. I used a wrong csv file before.